# Implement SqliteClientSyncProvider in Client & Server Synchronization Scenario?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, synchronization

I want to implement a Client(SQLite) & Server(SQL Server) Synchronization application using MS Sync Framework and SqliteClientSyncProvider (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteclientsyn/)

```
syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqliteClientSyncProvider(clientSqlConn);
syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("filtered_customer", serverConn, null, "Sync");
syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

After Synchronize() execution a got an InvalidCastExcpetion :

```
InvalidCastExcpetion : Microsoft.Synchronisation.KnowledgeSyncProvider
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the SyncAgent instead of the SyncOrchestrator. The SqlLiteClientSyncProvider is an older anchor-based offline provider that doesn't use the newer knowledge-based peer-to-peer type of sync provider.

in you example above, you can't mix and match providers as well. so if you're using SQL Server for the remote provider part, you must use the older DBServerSyncProvider as well.